# Messaging - dealing with out-of-order messages in an at-least once messaging system

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design, messaging, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm currently working on implementing a messaging based system (also using a mixture DDD, CQRS, event sourcing etc, as appropriate). The general pattern being used is at-least-once messaging with de-duping consumers/idempotent receivers.

One sticking point is out of order messages. An approach advocated by Vaughn Vernon in his book [Implementing Domain Driven Design](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Implementing-Domain-Driven-Design-Vaughn-Vernon/dp/0321834577) (chapter 13, roughly p475 onwards) is to use a MemberChangeTracker, which checks the date of the messages and behaves accordingly (the example given is a Disable  message arrives *after* an Enable  message, despite being generated first. The change tracker checks the date occurred and only applies the second message coming in (the Disable msg) if the date occurred is subsequent to the last received event.

This is messy. The compensating behaviour is difficult and the combinations could explode fairly quickly. Vaughn's answer is "simple": don't take responsibility for data in an external system, which makes sense. However, if you do need to do this, is there a better approach?

My question is: could each consumer subscribe to every single event from a given Aggregate, keep track of the message order (so each event would have a message order number on it: Creation = 1; UpdateToAggregate = 2; Cancel = 3) and  filter only for the ones it is interested in? Doing this would allow the consumer to see that the Enable message it receives is out of order, and wait until it receives the "missing" message (in this case, Disable, or it could just be one it's not even interested in)? This would allow the consumer to apply messages in order and simplify it's handler logic significantly.

**Is this a valid approach?** What are the trade-offs here (e.g. delayed message processing waiting for in-order messages to arrive)? This seems a logical - albeit slightly uncomfortable, as every consumer has to subscribe to *every* message, not nice - approach. Would this be practical?

Comment: I am quite confused by your question. What are "consumers" and to what event are they subscribing? Domain Events, if they are external to your aggregage? Or aggregate change events that are coming via your event store? In any case, one event handler handles one and only one type of event, why is there a question? Versions are enforced on aggregate level, this is pretty much mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

When you're working with aggregates, every consumer has to build an aggregate from messages stream OR from snapshot + messages stream after the snapshot. So, you don't have to run through all messages for particular aggregate, if there are too many messages. Aside from that, I don't see how else you can make sense of some portion of messages while skipping other portion.